# Инфинитив в функции ПГС

Tags: синтаксис

На сайте Лицей в пособии Курс русского языка (авторы: д.ф.н., проф. Л.В.Балашов, д.ф.н. проф. Дементьева В.В.) утверждают, что ПГС может быть выражено независимым инфинитивом. Жить — родине служить.

Однако в одном из своих ответов (на вопрос об инфинитиве в СИС: Его утеха по лесам скитаться) Людмила говорит, что вышеприведенный пример относится к СИС.

А может, у кого-н. есть источники, утверждающие, что это СИС? Ну или ПГС. За исключением, конечно, того учебника, который я привел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как подобные сказуемые характеризовали **Розенталь** и **Добромыслов**  (*В.А. Добромыслов и Д.Э. Розенталь "Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания. Пособие для учителей." Выпуск второй. М., 1960*):

> По своей функции инфинитив в предложениях *Учить — ум точить; Цель
>   наша — правду отстоять, мир для людей* и т. п. ближе стоит к
>   предикативному члену (именной части) **именного сказуемого**. <...> 
>   Не следует также забывать, что неопределенная форма глагола по
>   происхождению — имя и что в настоящее время инфинитив соотносится с
>   именем существительным, например *Наша задача — учиться* и *Наша
>   задача — учение*.
>
> Правда, самый термин "именное сказуемое" предполагает наличие в нём
>   какого-нибудь имени (существительного, прилагательного, числительного,
>   местоимения). Однако, как известно, предикативный член может быть
>   выражен также причастием, деепричастием (очень редко), наречием (в том
>   числе предикативным наречием, или безлично-предикативным словом),
>   междометием, т. е. частями речи, которые к именам не относятся (только
>   причастие стоит к ним ближе как именная глагольная форма). **В плане
>   такой условности можно отнести сюда и инфинитив...**

Такой же точки зрения придерживается и **Лекант П.А.** (*Современный русский язык. М., 2007*):

> Инфинитив в **составном именном сказуемом** не утрачивает значение
>   действия, но выступает в качестве характеристики предмета (или
>   другого, независимого действия), названного в подлежащем. Инфинитив
>   сочетается только со связками *быть, значить, означать*:
>
> ...*Наша учительская миссия — защитить детскую душу*.

То же — и у **Шапиро**: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304304

То же — и **Гайсиной Р.М.** (*Синтаксис простого предложения в современном русском языке. М., 2010*).

То же — и у **Кустовой Г.И.** (*Синтаксис современного русского языка. М., 2013*)...

**СИС** — у большинства известных мне грамматистов. Но не у всех…

*У **Литневской** (Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников*) — **"особый тип СГС"**:

> **Особый тип СГС** представлен в предложениях, главные члены которых выражены глаголами в неопределенной форме: *Волков бояться — в лес не
>   ходить*.
>
> http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31202

**Федосюк М.Ю.** (*Синтаксис современного русского языка. М., 2012*) такие сказуемые называет **инфинитивными**:

> **Инфинитивными сказуемыми** будем называть сказуемые, которые выражены при помощи независимых инфинитивов, например: *Наша задача —
>   учиться; Жизнь прожить — не поле перейти*…

Итого: **СИС, особый тип СГС, инфинитивное сказуемое**… Ну и **простое глагольное сказуемое**, как у Балашовой с Дементьевым.

К сожалению, ГОСТов в лингвистике нет...

Comment: Slava, спасибо.   Все это я читал на  форуме Грамоты.ру. Поэтому был удивлен, когда увидел, что подобные конструкции относят к ПГС. И что странное. С Балашовой и Дементьевом согласились лингвисты сайта Современный русский.

Comment: _Серж: С Балашовой и Дементьевом согласились лингвисты сайта Современный русский._ === А где можно было бы ознакомиться с их ответом?

Comment: Мнений много  (СИС, особый тип СГС, инфинитивное сказуемое и т.д.), да логика как-то мало прослеживается.  Есть общепринятое  определение для сказуемого, есть определение для предложения как грамматической единицы (в обоих случаях присутствует время и наклонение как показатели предикативности).  Ни и как инфинитив согласуется с этими  определениями? Тут не ГОСТы нужны, а ясные  логические связи в терминологии.

Comment: _Sharon: Есть общепринятое определение для сказуемого…_ === Блажен, кто верует…

Comment: Нет общих определений? Правда? А тогда что стоит Ваш грамматический дайджест? Если наши лингвисты  говорят "на разных языках", то стоит ли  вообще сравнивать их позиции по отдельным темам, что-то обсуждать и время напрасно терять? Тогда надо выбирать для себя "правильную" грамматическую школу и ориентироваться на нее.

Comment: https://ask.fm/russian#  Slava, вот здесь вы можете ознакомиться с их ответом.

Comment: Я не смог скопировать ссылку именно на их ответ. Но их ответ находится под номером 100 -105. Там легко найти. Каждый ответ в белых квадратиках.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Я всё нашёл и скопировал. Ответившему на Ваши вопросы, что  "точка зрения", которую они вам привели, "всегда считалась классической и общепринятой в школьной традиции" **не верьте**. Розенталь-то  Добромыслов как раз школьникам и учителям на аналогичный вопрос в своё время и отвечали. Какой-то учитель мог учить своих учеников и по-иному, но о **традиции** говорить, не подкрепив такие слова ссылками на учебники, некорректно.  Попросите своего _корреспондента_ прокомментировать ответ Розенталя с Добромысловым, на который я ссылался выше...

Comment: ...Может, он не будет после ознакомления с этим ответом столь категоричен и изменит своё утверждение о "традиции"?

Comment: @slava1947,  я задал этот вопрос одному из авторов этого учебника в фейсбуке. Пока ответа нет. Он не заходил еще. Меня смущает то, что авторы учебника достаточно серьезные ученые.

Answer (score 2):

Серж, Вы же знаете, что это один из **переходных** случаев в синтаксисе, да и в морфологии инфинитив вызывает много вопросов в силу того что по происхождению - это форма дательного падежа единственного числа отглагольного имени существительного, впоследствии утратившего остальные падежи и перешедшего в систему глагола. Так что он вполне может входить в состав СИС, ведь исторически это именная форма, втянутая в систему глагольных форм.

В старославянском  языке инфинитив мог быть дополнением также и при существительном или прилагательном. 
Древнерусскому  языку  было  свойственно  употребление  инфинитива  в  функции  подлежащего, к началу письменности это  уже не имя, а  глагольная категория. В процессе изучения инфинитив называли по-разному  -  «особой  частью  речи»,  «неопределенным  наклонением»,  «глагольным  номинативом», «смешанной частью речи»,  «подглаголком», «отглаголией», «неопределенной формой».

В предложениях типа ***Жить — родине служить.*** инфинитив - синкретичный член предложения.

Синкретичность инфинитива объясняется многообразием выполняемых им синтаксических функций: инфинитив может быть одним из главных членов двусоставного предложения. В функции главного члена (сказуемого) односоставного предложения выступает так называемый независимый инфинитив. Например: *Молчать! Загремел лесник и шагнул два раза (Тургенев). Вам не видать таких сражений… (Лермонтов).* Независимому инфинитиву противостоит зависимый. Его синтаксические функции более разнообразны, завися от того или иного слова в предложении, такой инфинитив является или **частью составного сказуемого**, или одним из второстепенных членов предложения.

Артамонов В.Н.называет предложения по схеме ИНФ.- ИНФ. биинфинитивными, другие учёные называют их предложениями-тождествами.

https://science-education.ru/ru/article/view?id=9041

Многие говорят о препозиции подлежащего в таких предложениях, но ведь допускается и инверсия. Если жить-подлежащее, то смысл предложения: *жизнь - это служба родине, жизнь является службой родине*, но мне видится более логичным смысл обратный: *служба родине является жизнью* (самым важным смыслом жизни), тогда получается, что **жить - сказуемое, а служить - подлежащее**.

О том, что инфинитив может быть частью СИС, говорится вот на этих сайтах: 
https://studopedia.ru/12_60476_nachavshiysya-vek.html

https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200304304

На отдельных сайтах можно найти это предложение как иллюстрацию простого глагольного сказуемого, но Вы ведь понимаете, что тогда мы должны иметь возможность заменить инфинитив личной формой глагола, ну вот как *А Татьяна бежать! - А Татьяна как побежит!* У нас такой возможности нет.

Если это СГС, то должен быть вспомогательный фазисный глагол или модальная форма, у нас этого тоже нет.

Остаётся только СИС, ***Жить - (это) родине служить***.

Comment: Я все это знаю. Но я поэтому спросил здесь, потому что авторы профессора. Работают в самарском университете. Их перу принадлежат многочисленные научные работы. Не может быть, что они не знали этой точки зрения.

Comment: Думал, может я чего-то не знаю.